# The msi log file status does not reflect the installation files status

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade

Trying to upgrade the msi in which a component has its ID,GUID and FileID are changed using harvesting.
I am expecting WiX to treat this as a new component and install it straight away. The log also shows states the same

MSI (s) (00:14) [21:23:39:980]: Component: NLog.config; Installed: Absent; Request: Local; Action: Local

As the Installed State is absent and the Request and Action are local, the component should be installed.
But NLog.config is not getting installed in our case.

Did anyone else face the same issue or have a solution for this?

Comment: Please try to do a repair of your MSI and see if the file is present afterwards. Also: please report the location in the InstallExecuteSequence of the standard action "RemoveExistingProducts". Is it at the end of the sequence list? Sort the table by the Sequence column.

Comment: It might be because you are overwriting a text file (.config) which essentially doesn't have a version.  You might need to look into using 'companion files' to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, using a companion file should solve at least part of the problem. I have a sample if you are still looking at this? You must also understand the implications of how you configure your major upgrade to happen (if it happens early or late during the installation process).

Comment: Take a look at your msi log file again. What you've posted above is the desired/planned component action, but during the InstallFiles standard action you'd actually see your file being processed - and it is there that it will log why that file is not being installed/overwritten.

Comment: I have a few answers on companion files: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60854570/129130), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434514/129130), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54766353/129130) - and probably a few more.